# Creating one to many relations in neo4j

Tags: csv, graph, neo4j, cypher

so I'm very new to using a graph database, and I have chosen neo4j. I'm trying to make a simple recommending system based on the graph nodes.

**So I have my original dataset that is a CSV that looks like this:**

[image]

Since some of the fields have Semicolons, I separated them and parsed it to a new CSV. (Basically made every combination of fields)

**New CSV looks like this:**

[image]

> Above image is just shown for N2, I have done the same thing for N1 and N3 aswell.

Now, I need to create nodes and relations in such a way that each

- `Name` KNOWS `Language`
- `Name` WORKED_WITH `Database`.

**Hence, I ran the following query:**

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row
CREATE (n:Name {name: row.Name})
CREATE (l: Language {language: row.Language})
CREATE (d: Database {database: row.Database})
CREATE (n)-[:KNOWS]->(l)
CREATE (n)-[:WORKED_WITH]->(d)
```

**This is the following output I get:**

[image]

> Only shown for N2 nodes

Since I want to build a recommender, my idea was to link the `name` to `language` and `database`.

**Expected output:**

[image]

> I want to link it in this way so I can count the total number of incoming nodes on a Language or Database to recommend it.

Can someone tell me where I'm going wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use **CREATE clause it creates new nodes each time**.

If you want to **use the existing node and create only if it doesn't exist** then you need to use **MERGE** clause instead of **CREATE**.

Here is your query with MERGE:

```
LOAD CSV WITH HEADERS FROM "file:///data.csv" AS row
MERGE (n:Name {name: row.Name})
MERGE (l: Language {Language: row.Language})
MERGE (d: Database {database: row.Database})
MERGE (n)-[:KNOWS]->(l)
MERGE (n)-[:WORKED_WITH]->(d)
```